# White border position:fixed even if margin:0 and padding:0

Tags: html, css, border, css-position, removing-whitespace

This white border is driving me crazy in IE and Edge, it does not appear in Chrome and Firefox.

If you follow the link:

[Might.to](http://might.to)

You will see that at the bottom of the page there is a white space of around 1 pixel high. I tried the common ways (after researching) to fix this:

```
body {
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   border:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
```

In my CSS:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   margin-top:0;
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```

The white space only appears when I use position:fixed on my nav div (the top part). I want the "top" section to stick as the user browse through the website.

I looked around and I tried all solutions I could find on Stack Overflow or Google to no avail.

And I am unfortunately running out of ideas, can anyone help me out with this please?

Most of the site is made of "placeholders" for now, I want to fix the bugs and display glitches before changing everything.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] instead of linking to an off-site webpage. Stack Overflow has a really cool feature called "Stack Snippets" that lets you run HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in a demo sandbox inside of a post here.

Comment: Greetings, I'll do a more compact version of the website (with the issue) and I'll add it as a snippet afterward. Thanks for letting me know of that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none;
```

Comment: Greetings, I tried the above in both body {} and nav {} and I still have the problem.